# ¿Por qué esto es un Objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
const user = function() {
    return {
        nombre: 'generico',
        apellido: 'generico',
    }
}();
```

y esto otro es una función:

```
const user = function() {
return {
    nombre: 12,
    apellido: 23,
}
```

};

no termino de comprender la diferencia, e incluso, noté que si hago lo siguiente:

```
const user = function() {
    let names = ['Pedro','Perez']
    return {
        nombre:names[0],
        apellido:names[1],
    }
}();
```

la variable names es como que es 'privada' o algo así, porque desde afuera no hay manera de acceder, imagino que obviamente también por una cuestión de alcance de la variable ... ¿pero esto sería una forma de mantener algo de forma 'privada', por así decirlo?

A la hora de imprimir por consola typeof user me devuelve function, sin los (), y con los () me devuelve que es un object .... pasa que si en vez de ser un let es un var la consola al querer imprimirlo no lo puedo imprimir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para el primer caso estas definiendo una función anónima, finalmente con los paréntesis la estas llamando sin ningún parámetro por lo que a la constante user se le asigna el objecto que esta retornando de la función

```
( user = {nombre: 'generico', apellido: 'generico' } ).
```

Al contrario en el segundo caso la función anónima no esta siendo llamada por lo que user es apunta a la función no a el resultado de ella, ahora user es una función y puedes hacer uso de ella con user().

Para le tercer caso sucedo lo mismo que en el primero la constante user esta siendo asignada con el objecto que retorna la función.

Comment: Genial mas que aclarado muchisimas gracias !!!